# can't validate true or false var_dump in laravel carbon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I write code to check current time between 2 times $start and $end like this:

```
$current = new Carbon();
$start = product::select('dateS')->where('id',$req->id)->first(); 
$end = product::select('dateE')->where('id',$req->id)->first();
$val= var_dump($current->between($start->dateS,  $end->dateE));
```

It work and when i use `dd($val)`  it will show:

bool(false)
null or bool(true) null

Next, i want to do like this but  it only returns else case. What did I do wrong?

```
 if($val == true){
      echo "current time is between start and end";
    }
    else{
      echo "current time isn't between start and end";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... so you want `$val = $current->between(...)`? also you don't need to do 2 separate queries to get those 2 fields from the same record

Comment: i just want result `$val` iwhen show in `dd($val)` is bool(true) true or bool(false) false to validate with if-else

Comment: `$val` in your current code is `null` (`false`) as `var_dump()` returns `void` (nothing) ... so you need to remove the `var_dump` call from that assignment

Comment: var_dump https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php does not return anything. So $val will not contain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get start and end as below:

```
$start_and_end_time = product::where('id',$req->id)->select(['dateS', 'dateE'])->first();
```

If you have set date cast to `dateS` and `dateE` in your **Product** model, you'll get carbon instances by the above query.

**Product** model

```
dates = [
    'dateS',
    'dateE'
];
```

So, you can compare current datetime with the `dateS` and `dateE` as below:

```
$val = \Carbon::now()->between($start_and_end_time->dateS, $start_and_end_time->dateE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your code to remove the `var_dump` call from the assignment and you should be fine:

```
$current = new Carbon();
$product = product::findOrFail($req->id, ['dateS', 'dateE']);

if ($current->between($product->dateS, $product->dateE)) {
    echo "current time is between start and end";
} else {
    echo "current time isn't between start and end";
}
```

Also combined the queries as you only need 1 query to get the needed data.